# CentOS Stream graphical package management tool / dnf frontend

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, repository, dnf

I've just installed fresh and wet CentOS Stream.

Unfortunately yumex-dnf is no longer in the default repos.

Is it dead?
What was it replaced by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yumex-DNF is [no longer being developed](https://github.com/timlau/yumex-dnf/blob/develop/README.md) and was replaced by [dnfdragora](https://github.com/manatools/dnfdragora) in Fedora. There is a [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1769168) asking for it to be packaged in EPEL 8, but it seems to be abandoned too. You can try installing it manually, but it might not be easy because [libyui](https://github.com/libyui/libyui) is also not available in CentOS 8 repositories so you'll need to install it manually too.

GNOME Software is available in CentOS 8 Stream, but that's probably not what are you looking for, it's more "high level" and I'd consider it more GUI for PackageKit than DNF.

Comment: In other words there is no native graphical tool in CentOS and I need to stick to dnf, right?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. GNOME Software is available in CentOS 8 repositories, but that's not really GUI for dnf (I added that to the answer).

Comment: Thanks, I am exactly of the same opinion. I wonder however why is it so difficult to create a universal rpm package manager and its GUI version. Besides Debian-based system we have a wild west here.

Comment: All Debian based system use `apt` so it's easier to create a single GUI app for them. With RPM "ecosystem" we have yum/dnf in RHEL/Fedora, zypper in SUSE and urpmi in Mandriva based distributions so it's harder. And I guess demand for such application isn't that big -- I use `dnf` in Fedora and don't really need GUI for that (and I didn't really use Synaptic on Debian/Ubuntu either).

Comment: For me Synaptic is very useful to mark all upgrades and than review them and unmark the ones that may break some apps. With command line it is not that easy to create the list and just manually skip, possible but inconvenient.